# Check if a certain word is in a txt file using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I made a program **based on user input** and I am using txt files with my program to check if the user input equal to the txt file.

```
my_age = open('c:\\file\\user_ask_about_my_age')
my_age_read = my_age.read()
user = raw_input("ask")
if user in my_Age_read:
   print "I am 10 years old "
```

the txt file:

```
what is your age
how old are you
```

The problem is if the user types any char that is existed in my txt(ask_about...) the program print `I am 10 years old`.

**How to make my program read the txt file like string for each line?**

I need a simple way and a small code to fix my problem because I have a lot of text files.

Comment: Add the content of ```my_file.py``` to a function (could be in any file) and call that from your program?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your other file is in the same directory, then on top of your script you can do add:

```
import myfile
```

If this file contains a function to print what you want to print, you can call this function with

```
myfile.print_function()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you ask this way:

```
with open('c:\\file\\user_ask_about_my_age', 'r') as fd:
    lines = fd.readlines()
lines = [line.strip('\n') for line in lines]
user = raw_input("ask")
for line in lines:
    if user == line:
        print "i am 10 years old "
```

Comment: thanks, but i have a lot of text files i cant do that for each one is There a simple way??